# Broken TSQL XML common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, common-table-expression

SQL Server says: 'The multi-part identifier "shinola.a" could not be bound.'

What did I do wrong here?

```
declare @foo table (
    a int,
    b int
);

insert into @foo values ( 1, 2 ), ( 3, 4 );

declare @xml XML = '<shinola><a>1</a><b>5</b></shinola>';

-- OK, now this is where it breaks: 
with shinola ( a, b ) as (
    select
        sh.value('a[1]', 'int') as a,
        sh.value('b[1]', 'int') as b
    from
        @xml.nodes('/shinola') as doc(sh)
) 
update @foo
set
    b = shinola.b
where 
    a = shinola.a
```

(I know there are other ways to do this, and I just checked in one of them in the code I'm writing. I want to understand what I don't understand about THIS way of doing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The error message is caused by `shinola.a` expression (`where 
    a = shinola.a`) which can not be found by SQL Server in `from` clause of `update` statement or in `@foo` table. As you can see, at this moment, `shinola` common table expression isn't referenced by `update` statement.

2) If you want to update `@foo` table variable using data from `shinola` common table expression then you could use `UPDATE ... FROM ...` thus:

```
...
with shinola ( a, b ) as (
...
) 
update  @foo
set     b = shinola.b
from    @foo as [target]
inner join shinola on [target].a = shinola.a;

select * from @foo;
```

Results:

```
a           b
----------- -----------
1           5    <-- updated row
3           4
```

3) This `update` isn't safe because the "relation" between target table (`@foo`) and source (`shinola`) isn't 1-1, 1-0 but 1-n (for example).

Example: if you change @xml variable thus (1-55, 1-5):

```
declare @xml XML = '<shinola><a>1</a><b>55</b></shinola>
<shinola><a>1</a><b>5</b></shinola>';
```

then the result will be:

```
a           b
----------- -----------
1           55     <-- row a=1 is updated with `55` instead of `5` (SQL Server choose a single value from the source. In this case the selected value was `55` instead of `5`).
3           4
```

A safer version of `update` statement could be in this case:

```
...
with shinola ( a, b ) as (
...
) 
update  @foo
set     b = (select shinola.b  from shinola where [target].a = shinola.a)
--or better to avoid updating with NULLs 
--set   b = ISNULL( (select shinola.b  from shinola where [target].a = shinola.a) , b )
from    @foo as [target]
```

because it will raise an error in this case:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

4) Better, you should decide in such cases what to do when you have a one to many "relation" between target and source. For example, you could choose the minimum (`5`), maximum (`55`) value or you could choose the average value (`30`):

```
declare @foo table (
    a int,
    b int
);

insert into @foo values ( 1, 2 ), ( 3, 4 );

declare @xml XML = '<shinola><a>1</a><b>55</b></shinola>
<shinola><a>1</a><b>5</b></shinola>';

with shinola ( a, b ) as (
    select sh.value('a[1]', 'int') as a, sh.value('b[1]', 'int') as b
    from @xml.nodes('/shinola') as doc(sh)
) 
update  @foo
-- if there are many value in the source (`shinola`) it finds the maximum value
set b = ISNULL( (select max(shinola.b)  from shinola where [target].a = shinola.a) , b )
from    @foo as [target];

select * from @foo;
```

Results:

```
a           b
----------- -----------
1           55
3           4
```

5) For SQL Server 2008+ you could use MERGE thus:

```
declare @foo table (
    a int,
    b int
);

insert into @foo values ( 1, 2 ), ( 3, 4 );

declare @xml XML = '<shinola><a>1</a><b>55</b></shinola>
<shinola><a>1</a><b>5</b></shinola>';

with base ( a, b ) as (
    select sh.value('a[1]', 'int') as a, sh.value('b[1]', 'int') as b
    from @xml.nodes('/shinola') as doc(sh)
), shinola ( a, max_b ) as (
    select a, MAX(b)
    from base 
    group by a
)
merge into @foo as [target]
using shinola on [target].a = shinola.a
when matched then 
    update set b = shinola.max_b;

select * from @foo;
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm starting to get it now.